# Xamarin - Android service - independent deployment

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am currently developing a Xamarin Forms app. The app has two main component:
- the application itself.
- a long running service that listen for event coming from an Azure IotHub.

My question is about the implementation of android service (for windows and ios, I have different issues...).

When a new message comes in, the service sends a new intent to notify the app.
The app has a specific broadcast receiver to listen to new messages (in case of the app is not running).

For the moment, the app and the service are deployed together. I'd like to test independent deployment for the app and the android service:

- Because the app and the service are deployed together, I assume they are sharing the same sandbox container and the same memory ? Am I right ?
- Is is possible to deploy a stand alone service using Xamarin and how to do this ?

Comment: `stand alone service`? You can do it via a completely separate app and the first app can call the second app via an explicit Intent : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39325553/4984832

Comment: Yeah I want the service to run into its own process. maybe it does not make sense. The link sounds good, thanks !

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, you can assign different processes, via the manifest (`android:process`), within the same app but you need to review the process lifecycle within an app to determine if that is really what you need: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: The truth is that the app consume a lot of memory and I d like the service to run separately

Comment: The Java per process heap size can be as low as 16MB for a low end / small screen device, but since we are talking about `Xamarin.Android`, you have two VMs to deal with and where are those objects being allocated. If they are JNI/Java peer objects, then the Java heap will play a role and the Java Heap size is limiting factor. If those objects are C# managed objects and NOT peer-objects (crossing the Java/C# bridge) then you can basically alloc memory till your RAM is depleted, or the memory size request is rejected due to memory fragmentation....

Comment: So the net result of that is, if you are dealing with lots of objects that transverse the Java/C# bridge, go with different app/differen processes, but if your main memory consumption is all pure C# based, then one app/one process is all you need since if you get OOM, your RAM is full  / the OS denied the Mono NDK-based allocation.... having multiple apps/multiple processes will not help, but actually hurt as each running app has an overhead just for running....

Comment: Ok Thanks a lots. It seems that I am stuck for the moment ;-)